# This session is invalid.You are logged in through other browser

Tags: internet-explorer-11, loadrunner, vugen, truclient

Getting following error message from browser at the time of recording as well as replay, '**This session is invalid.You are logged in through other browser.**

This issue does not appear when logging in manually as well as through TruClient Firefox.

I am using following,
Vugen : 12.02

IE: 11

Please help me with this & let me know if required more information on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting all Java Temporary files solved this issue.

Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Java -> Temporary Internet Files [Settings] -> Delete Files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to correlate all dynamic session variables. You have some elements which are hard coded and once you replay multiple users together you have a session violation where the same browser cannot exist in two different places at the same time.

Comment: Firstly i tried to run the script only with single user. Regarding the correlation of dynamic session variables, can you give some example of doing it or may be more information considering this is TruClient Script

Comment: "You are logged in through other browser."  Make sure that your user ID and password is different for each user.  So, if you are signed on in another browser then you will again violate the same person in two locations rule.   TruClient automatically handles session items.  This appears to be a business rule violation where you still have an active session under the same user ID on the web server.

Comment: I am able to log in to this application on two different machines at the same time manually.

Comment: Have you spoken with the application developers to understand where and when this message gets generated?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, please try LR 12.02 patch 3, which solves some known TruClient issues on IE 11, mainly on user separations.